# How to loop through all images (all of equal size), 2 images per page, with tikzpicture and tcolorbox on every page?

Tags: graphics, foreach, loops, includegraphics, page

Please consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand\UseImage[1]{%
\IfFileExists{#1.jpg}%
  {\includegraphics[scale=\ImageScale]{#1.jpg}}%
    {\includegraphics[scale=\ImageScale]{example-image.jpg}}%
}

% =======================================
% Input ===================================
\def\BottomTitle{Bottom Title}
\def\ImageScale{0.5}
\def\ImageLeft{\UseImage{SomeImageName-1}}
\def\ImageRight{\UseImage{SomeImageName-17}}
%
\newcommand{\PictureIndexStartsAt}{1}
\newcommand{\PictureIndexEndsAt}{16}
% =======================================
% =======================================

\begin{document}

% Page Box: 
\begin{tcolorbox}[]
% Images: 
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=2, raster force size=false]
\tcbitem[remember as=LeftRasterbox, width=9cm] \ImageLeft
\tcbitem[remember as=RightRasterbox, width=9cm] \ImageRight
\end{tcbitemize} % remeber as=<name> for later TikZ-usage
%
\tcblower
\BottomTitle
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% ................ Here is more code that should be on every page, at the same spot

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can see, that, if the files exist, the left image should print `SomeImageName-1.jpg` and the right image should print `SomeImageName-17.jpg` **on page 1**.

In other words, we currently have:

- `SomeImageName-1.jpg` (page 1, left)
- `SomeImageName-17.jpg` (page 1, right)

There is also some more `tikzpicture` code which needs to be print **on every page**, as well as some titles (such as `BottomTitle` in the example) inside a `tcolorbox`, which also need to be print **on every page**, as can be understood from the MWE.

### Now the question:

How to loop this, such that we have the following:

- `SomeImageName-1.jpg` (page 1, left)
- `SomeImageName-17.jpg` (page 1, right)
- `SomeImageName-2.jpg` (page 2, left)
- `SomeImageName-18.jpg` (page 2, right)
- `...-3.jpg` (p. 3 ...
- `...-19.jpg` (p. 3 ...
- and so forth untill `-16.jpg` (p. 16 ...
- and so forth untill `-32.jpg` (p. 16 ...

In short:

How to have a loop, such that multiple pages can be print, each loaded with 2 images per page, as per the loop description above?

Probably something with

- `\foreach \i in {\PictureIndexStartsAt,...,\PictureIndexEndsAt}{`
- `\def\iPlusConstant{\the\numexpr\i+16}`
- LEFT: `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./Pictures/XYZ-\i.jpg}`
- RIGHT: `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./Pictures/XYZ-\iPlusConstant.jpg}`
- `\newpage`

How to piece this together into a loop which works with this MWE please?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand\UseImageLeft[1]{%
\IfFileExists{#1\i.jpg}%
  {\includegraphics[scale=\ImageScale]{#1\i.jpg}}%
    {\includegraphics[scale=\ImageScale]{example-image.jpg}}%
}

\newcommand\UseImageRight[1]{%
\IfFileExists{#1\iPlusConstant.jpg}%
  {\includegraphics[scale=\ImageScale]{#1\iPlusConstant.jpg}}%
    {\includegraphics[scale=\ImageScale]{example-image.jpg}}%
}

% Input ===================================
\def\ImageScale{0.2}
\def\ImageLeft{\UseImageLeft{Image-}}
\def\ImageRight{\UseImageRight{Image-}}
\newcommand{\PictureIndexStartsAt}{1}
\newcommand{\PictureIndexEndsAt}{16}
\def\iPlusConstant{\the\numexpr\i+16}
% =======================================

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {\PictureIndexStartsAt,...,\PictureIndexEndsAt}{

% On any page (begin)
\begin{tcolorbox}[]
\begin{tcbitemize}[]
\tcbitem[] \ImageLeft
\tcbitem[] \ImageRight
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
% On any page (end)

\newpage
}

\end{document}
```